# Is there a framework that can be used to encode & decode for video streaming based on IOS?

Tags: ios, video-streaming, decode, encode, codec

Does anyone who knows what's the framework or APIs should be instead of FFMPEG library on iOS?

Because it takes the high CPU if use the FFMPEG library to encode and decode the video streaming, and the performance is too slowly.

So i want to research an new way to improve the performance. But on iOS, apple don't allow the application to access hardware layer API, so that we can't invoke the apis that can be codec the video streaming by the hardware layer.

After searching with google, i found there is a library can do that, but no demo is rendered, here is the website:http://www.foxitsolutions.com/iphone_h264_sdk.html

is there anyone can answer my question and give me an solution??

Answer (score 0):

Use AVFoundation.You can use official [AVPlayerDemo](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AVPlayerDemo/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010101) to test it.

Comment: this framework is used the hardware layer codec to encode and decode? Thanks , i will research it

Comment: I think AVFoundation is just used to read the video data from .MOV file and write data to the other .MOV file, but how can i to use this framework to encode the received real-time video streaming buffer from another iOS device terminal and decode the send video streaming buffer from  my iOS device? is there anyway?

Comment: Because of the low performance of FFMPEG codec library, i need to change the current implement way with apple's hardware accelerate code c, but it's limited to application. We are not the right to access, it 's not a public API.

Comment: Could anyone help us to review the following way is right?
 precondition:
   1. there are two ios devices, and the main function of my   application is send and receive the real-time video streaming via network.

Comment: Steps:
  1.in the cameraOutput callback function, use the AVFoundation writer to write the real-time video streaming to a temp .mov file and send this temp file to server
  2. and then the other ios device get the temp file from server, and then read the video data from this file, and showing.

I think this way is low CPU used and with the high performance, because we always used the hardware codec to handle video streaming, not the software, but we have to upload the temp .mov file to server and then download it to show real-time. Does anybody have the best way?